# Amdahl's law example

Tags: cpu-architecture

Can someone help me with this example please and show me how to work the second part?

the question is :

> If one third of a weather prediction algorithm is inherently serial and the remainder 
>   parallelizable, what is the minimum number of cores needed to guarantee a 150% speedup over a 
>   single core implementation?
>
> ii. Your boss revises the figure to 200%. What is your new answer?

Thanks very much in advance !!

Comment: @mudel Welcome to StackOverflow!  If this is homework, please add the "homework" tag to this question so that the community can respond appropriately to your request.

Answer (score 0):

Guess: If the algorithm is 1/3 serial and 2/3 parallel...I would think that each core you added would give you a 66% increase in performance...So for 150% increase, you'd need 3 more cores, and for a 200% increase, you'd need 4.

This is a guess. Your textbook might be more helpful :)

Comment: Why 66%? as @dbasnett said, with two cores you get exactly a 150% increase, no need of 3 cores. For 200% increase, I agree with you...

Comment: Why are you commenting on a answer I submitted over 3 years ago about some guy's math homework? He's probably graduated at this point! How did you even stumble upon this question? It's one thing to necro a relatively useful thread, but this question is junk, and so is my answer...

Comment: Yeah, maybe I shouldn't had to comment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the algorithm runs on a single core and takes 90 minutes then 30 minutes is for the serial part and 60 minutes for the parallel part.

Add a CPU:

30 is for the serial part and 30 for the parallel part(half of the 60 overlaps with the serial part).

90 / 60 = 150% increase.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late, but here are the answers:

1) 150% increase -> 2 cores at least required as `dbasnett` said;

2) 200% increase -> 4 cores at least required basing on the Amahld's law:

[image: foo+bar]

Here, 90 minutes overall required to perform the calculation. *P* is the actually enhanced part of the algorithm (the parallelizable part) which is 2/3 of 90, N is the number of cores, so when there's a core only:

[image: foo+bar]

You get 1, which means 100%, which is how the algorithm performs the standard way (without multi-core acceleration and therefore no parallelization speedup).

Now, we must find N number of cores for which the previous equation equals 2, where 2 means that the algorithm performs in half time (45 minutes instead of 90 when there's no parallelization) and therefore with a 200% speedup:

[image: foo+bar]

Since:

[image: foo+bar]

We see that:

[image: foo+bar]

[image: foo+bar]

[image: foo+bar]

[image: foo+bar]

So with 4 cores computing in parallel the 2/3 of the algoritm you get 200% speedup. The same goes for 150%, you will get 2, as `dbasnett` already told you.

Pretty simple.

Note that a complex algorithm may imply further divisions of its parallelizable parts (and in theory you can have a different number of processing units per parallelizable part concurrently):

You can further look at Wikipedia (there's also an example):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law#Description

Anyway, the principle is the same:

Let *T* be the time an algorithm needs to execute in order to complete, *A* be the serial part of it, B its parallelizable part and N the number of parallel CPUs, you can divide B in further small sections and perform calculations on each part:

[image: foo+bar]

[image: foo+bar]

You may for C, D, G e.g. adopt M CPUs instead of N (the speedup will of course differ if M != N).

And at the end, you will arrive at a point when having more CPUs doesn't matter anymore, since:

[image: foo+bar]

And your algorithm speedup will at most tend to total execution time (T) divided by the execution time of the Serial part only (A).

Therefore parallel calculation comes really handy only when you have low execution time for the serial part of your algorithm.